# Upload Puppeteer screenshot to Cloudinary with Axios

Tags: axios, upload, puppeteer, cloudinary

I'm trying to take a screenshot with Puppeteer and then upload it to Cloudinary with Axios. I'm not sure if I'm able to upload the Puppeteer binary, whether I should be setting it to base64, referencing it as a buffer, etc. Whatever I try, it seems to be fail silently.

Trying along the lines of this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const axios = require('axios');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.google.com');

const screenshot = await page.screenshot({
    encoding: 'binary'
});

await browser.close();

let data = {
    file: screenshot, upload_preset: 'abc123'
}

axios.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/def456/image/upload', data);
```

Replacing `data` with this static 1x1 pixel image works fine, so I guess there's an issue with image format, or perhaps needing to wrap stuff in promises? I'm also able to see the screenshot normally within the service I'm trying this within after all this has run.

```
let data = {
    file: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEX/TQBcNTh/AAAAAXRSTlPM0jRW/QAAAApJREFUeJxjYgAAAAYAAzY3fKgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=", upload_preset: 'abc123'
}
```

Comment: What is the response from the Upload API call you get back from Cloudinary, can you log that? Also, you could try setting the encoding to base64, grabbing that and prefixing with `data:image/png;base64,<base64_string>` and sending this as the `file` parameter value?

Comment: Yep; this worked. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const axios = require('axios');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.google.com');

let screenshot = await page.screenshot({
    encoding: 'base64'
});

await browser.close();

screenshot = 'data:image/png;base64,' + screenshot;

let data = {
    file: screenshot, upload_preset: 'abc123'
}

axios.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/def456/image/upload', data).then((response) => {
        console.log('worked', response);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('did not work', error);
    });
```